# How to execute stored procedure on Remote computer in an efficient way?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I am running `StoredProcedure1` on Remote1 and once I get the output value from `StoredProcedure1` of Remote1, I will pass the value as a parameter for `StoredProcedure2` (available on Remote2).

So, if I execute `StoredProcedure2` from Remote1 using

```
[Remote2].[db].[schema].[StoredProcedure]
```

will this `StoredProcudure2` really execute and process on Remote2 or Remote1?

Or if I create the same stored procedure like `StoredProcedure2` on `Remote1` and update the records of Remote2 from Remote1, will it take the same time to run?

Which one is the efficient way?

```
RemoteServer DB1
       (Stored Procedure1) @output1, @output2

EXEC [RemoteDB2].[DB2].[dbo].[StoredProcedure2] 
                 @Para1 = @output1, @Para2 = @output2

             |

RemoteServer DB2
       (Stored Procedure2) @Para1,@Para2
```

Comment: Confusing... Maybe you should [edit] the question and *severely*  elaborate on what your environment looks like, what you're trying to do and what your question is in that respect.

Comment: @stickybit can you check now?

Comment: A remote sproc call will execute remotely

Comment: @Charlieface Linked server and Remote Server are same or not?. I am trying to execute [ServerIP].[DBName].[Dbo].[StoredProcedure] with parameter

Comment: Yeah sorry same thing